# Pattern for mapping with identity and applying a side-effect

Tags: scala, monads, side-effects

Is there a clearer way of expressing the following pattern:

```
def getUser(id: String): Option[User] = ???

getUser("12345").map { user =>
  someSideEffect(user)
  user
}
```

Note how given a functor we map with the identity function but also apply the side-effecting function to the boxed value.

[`Future.andThen`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html#andThen[U](pf:PartialFunction[scala.util.Try[T],U])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[T]) does exactly this:

> Applies the side-effecting function to the result of this future, and
>   returns a new future with the result of this future.

Is there something like `Future.andThen` but in the general case for any functor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't anything out of the box. People often add it with something like this:

```
 object ImplicitUtils {
    implicit class Utils[T](val t: T) extends AnyVal {
       def tap(f: T => Unit): T = { f(t) ; t }
    }
 }
```

So that, now you can write:

```
 import ImplicitUtils._
 val user = getUser("foo").tap(someSideEffect)
```

Answer (score 3):

Scala 2.13 provides it out-of-the-box as [`tap`](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.0/scala/util/ChainingOps.html#tap[U](f:A=%3EU):A)

```
import scala.util.chaining._
Some(42) tap println
```

cats companion `mouse` has it as [`<|`](https://github.com/typelevel/mouse/blob/d20bb8825670dd91c0408ff0b94575df02c57eb2/shared/src/main/scala/mouse/any.scala#L10)

```
import mouse.all._
Some(42) <| println
```

which both output

```
Some(42)
res1: Some[Int] = Some(42)
```

There exists a closed issue on this topic in cats repo [Kestrel combinator for Monad/Functor #1559](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/issues/1559) and provision of `flatTap` but not `tap`.

Answer (score 2):

```
object FunctorAndThen {

  import cats.Functor
  import cats.implicits._
  import scala.language.higherKinds

  implicit class AndThen[F[_], A](val f: F[A])(implicit ev: Functor[F]) {
    def andThen(sideEffect: A => Unit): F[A] = {
      f.map(sideEffect)
      f
    }
  }
}

// Usage:

import FunctorAndThen._
import cats.implicits._

val result: Option[String] = Option("a").andThen(a => println(a))
println(result)
```